# Capture Autodesk Forge Url by C#

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

I have my own Forge APP now, but after I upload those rvt files I hope to get all of the URLs of those files. Can it be possible?Hope to get Url data automatically. Appreciate for all comments. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDgQm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of URL link do you want? The UI in your snapshot looks like the Fusion Team/BIM360 Team. So, I supposed that you want to view the model with Forge Viewer or download the Revit source file.

To access data of the Fusion Team/BIM360 Team, you can refer to [View Hub Model tutorial](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels).

To get data of your Revit files uploaded to the Fusion team, you will need to use those endpoints of Forge Data Management API

- [GET hubs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-GET/) -> [HubsApi#GetHubs](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/HubsApi.md#gethubs)
- [GET projects](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-hub_id-projects-GET/) -> [ProjectsApi#GetHubProjects](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/ProjectsApi.md#gethubprojects)
- [GET topFolders](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-hub_id-projects-project_id-topFolders-GET/) -> [ProjectsApi#GetProjectTopFolders](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/7c5317aafdaf1407de6d7bd773e24e4e80b50204/src/Autodesk.Forge/Api/ProjectsApi.cs)
- [GET folder contents](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/) -> [FoldersApi#GetFolderContents](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/FoldersApi.md#getfoldercontents)

Afterward,

- To view the Revit model with Forge View, you need to find the derivative urn under either version tip of the file by this path `relationships.derivatives.data.id`. e.g.

  ```js
  "derivatives": {
    "data": {
        "type": "derivatives",
        "id": "dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLnlDV0dSdUhnUW5PeENIdk1oalQxZEE_dmVyc2lvbj0x"
    },
    "meta": {
        "link": {
            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLnlDV0dSdUhnUW5PeENIdk1oalQxZEE_dmVyc2lvbj0x/manifest?scopes=global"
        }
    }
  },
  ```
- To download the Revit source file, you need to find the storage id under either version tip of the file by this path `relationships.storage.data.id`. e.g.

  ```js
  "storage": {
    "data": {
        "type": "objects",
        "id": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/0213357d-03b1-4ab1-95f6-bff154b775ae.ifc"
    },
    "meta": {
        "link": {
            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/0213357d-03b1-4ab1-95f6-bff154b775ae.ifc?scopes=global"
        }
    }
  }
  ```

Lastly, please be noted models stored on the Fusion Team/BIM360 Team is on demand translation. Before viewing the model with Forge Viewer, you must open the overview page of the model on your Fusion Team/BIM360 Team project's Web UI like the below, and ensure that here no veiw is loading, then you’re fine to open the model with Forge Viewer, Otherwise, it means your model translation job is still processing.

[image]

Comment: Dear @Eason Kang, thanks for your generous advice! I want to capture the URLs with each project so that I can generate QR codes.

Comment: Hi @Benjamin, thanks for clarifying, but unfortunately, as I know, only BIM360 Docs Autodesk Docs has the web URL shown in the API response. Fuson Team and BIM360 Team doesn't have this support. But let me double confirm with our engineering team.

Comment: Hi @Benjamin, I got the confirmation from our engineering team. It's unsupported for Fusion Team and BIM360 Team, unfortunately. If you have such need, I would advise you to use BIM360 Docs or Autodesk Docs instead.

Comment: Thank you for telling me this information, it is really helpful. I will like to try BIM360 Docs then. Is there any place where I can get that information for Web API?

Comment: Just follow the instruction above, and then you should find an attribute called `webView` under the path `links.webView` in the response for projects, folders, and items.

Comment: e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO35B.png

Comment: Dear @Eason Kang, thanks for solving my questions, I will take them as a solution. Appreciate it !